# Layout não cabe na tela após rotação

Tags: android, android-layout

Desenvolvi um aplicativo que funciona normalmente mas quando viro a tela para a orientação paisagem o *app* fica cortado e não da pra descer e visualizar o restante do conteúdo e também o AdMob que implementei só funciona na tela vertical, na horizontal não exibe anúncios, o que pode ser?

Vertical:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Horizontal:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Uma das formas de resolver seu problema é inserir seu conteúdo dentro de uma [Scrollview](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/ScrollView.html), respectivamente permite a barra de rolagem vertical. E uma outra maneira de você resolver é Explorando a Orientação do smartphone.

## 1. ScrollView

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="fill_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content">

    <LinearLayout 
        android:id="@+id/layout1"
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical">

        <!-- 
         Aqui será exibia nossa lista
         -->

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Para ter mais uma noção, note a imagem abaixo do esquema de ScrollView e HorizontalScrollView:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Este [link](https://examples.javacodegeeks.com/android/core/ui/scrollview/android-scrollview-example/) tem um exemplo bem fácil para te ajudar a fazer isso.

## 2. Explorando Orientação

Como sugerido nos comentários, você pode criar dois layouts diferentes de acordo com a orientação do smartphone.

```
res/
    layout/              # default (portrait)
        main.xml
    layout-land/         # landscape
        main.xml
    layout-large/        # large (portrait)
        main.xml
    layout-large-land/   # large landscape
        main.xml
```

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Dê uma lida aqui na documentação do Android sobre [Supporting Different Screens](https://developer.android.com/training/basics/supporting-devices/screens.html) que você terá mais noção.

Comment: Outra possibilidade, talvez melhor, é utilizar dois "layouts", um para a tela na horizontal e outro para a tela na vertical.

Comment: Sim @ramaral , retifiquei a resposta para melhorar o entendimento e mostrar que existe outras possibilidades.

Comment: Excelente resposta!

Comment: consegui resolver! obrigado.

Answer (score 0):

Pode criar dois layout ou usar scrool view  conforme abaixo!

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
 <RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior">

<ScrollView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent"
    android:id="@+id/scrollView"
    android:layout_marginTop="40dp">

    <LinearLayout
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:weightSum="1"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true">

        <ImageView
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="150px"
            android:src="@drawable/ico_login"
            android:layout_marginTop="100px"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90px"
            android:id="@+id/edtEmailLogin"
            android:hint="@string/emailUsuario"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_dialog_email"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            />

        <EditText
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="90px"
            android:inputType="textPassword"
            android:id="@+id/edtSenhaLogin"
            android:hint="@string/senhaUsuario"
            android:drawableLeft="@android:drawable/ic_lock_idle_lock"
            android:textAlignment="center"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"

            />

        <LinearLayout
            android:orientation="horizontal"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:weightSum="1"
            android:baselineAligned="false"
            android:layout_marginBottom="15dp"
            android:gravity="center">

            <Button
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnEntrar"
                android:text="@string/botaoEnviar"
                android:onClick="setContentView"

                />

            <Button
                android:layout_width="143dp"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/btnCancelar"
                android:text="@string/botaoCancelar"
                android:onClick="setContentView"
                android:layout_weight="0.27"

                />

        </LinearLayout>

    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```