# Como fazer o texto rolar na tela do android

Tags: android, android-layout

Eu estou querendo colocar em uma tela um texto grande.

Porém estou com um pequeno problema na hora de ler mais, o texto é simplesmente cortado e não tem como rolar para continuar lendo.

Alguém me indica um método para fazer isso?

Exemplo 1:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Exemplo 2:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Comment: Veja esta resposta com a solução: http://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/147688/35406

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Se eu entendi direito, basta colocar seu textview dentro de um Scrollview.

```
<ScrollView
  android:layout_width="match_parent"
  android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical" >   

          <TextView
              android:id="@+id/tv_long"
              android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="match_parent"
              android:text="@string/really_long_string" >
          </TextView>
   </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```