# Como fazer uma ScrollView com vários components?

Tags: android, rolamento

Estou tentando fazer com que uma activity de um projeto meu, contenha uma quantidade considerável de components.

Tentei fazer isso utilizando uma ScrollingActivity que contivesse mais do que somente o textView "padrão" (aquele que já vem quando a mesma é criada), porém descobri que não é possível, pelo menos que eu saiba.

A minha activity contém basicamente esse modelo:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Porém como devem imaginar ela não contém somente essas duas perguntas.

Também tentei um ScrollView, porém não devo ter feito o mesmo da maneira correta ou simplesmente o mesmo tem uma limitação de não poder "ultrapassar" o limite do layout.

Gostaria de saber como fazer para colocar tudo isso na activity:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

**Com a imagem quis expressar que o conteúdo que quero adicionar ultrapassa a mesma, a ponto de eu não ter conseguido utilizar um ScrollView.**

Fiz um modelo do código (somente com os dois primeiros buttons, perguntas e respostas) para o caso de ser útil para um melhor entendimento e/ou resposta:

**MainActivity:**

```js
package genesysgeneration.chinterative;

import android.support.v7.app.AppCompatActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.Button;
import android.widget.TextView;

public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements View.OnClickListener{

    private Button btnSim01, btnSim02, btnNao01, btnNao02;
    private TextView tvPergunta01, tvPergunta02, tvResposta01, tvResposta02;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        btnSim01=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSim01);
        btnSim02=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnSim02);
        btnNao01=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNao01);
        btnNao02=(Button)findViewById(R.id.btnNao02);

        tvPergunta01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPergunta01);
        tvPergunta02=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvPergunta02);
        tvResposta01=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResposta01);
        tvResposta02=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.tvResposta02);

    }

    public void onClick(View v){

        switch (v.getId()){
            
            case R.id.btnSim01:
                
                break;
            
            case R.id.btnNao01:
                
                break;
            
            case R.id.btnSim02:
                
                break;
            
            case R.id.btnNao02:
                
                break;
            
        }
        
    }

}
```

**activity_main.xml:**

```js
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    tools:context="genesysgeneration.chinterative.MainActivity">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPergunta01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:text="Pergunta 1" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResposta01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPergunta01"
        android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
        android:text="texto com a resposta baseada na escolha do button " />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvPergunta02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_centerVertical="true"
        android:text="pergunta 2" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSim01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPergunta01"
        android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
        android:text="sim" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNao01"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSim01"
        android:text="nao" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnSim02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnSim01"
        android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSim01"
        android:layout_below="@+id/tvPergunta02"
        android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
        android:text="sim" />

    <Button
        android:id="@+id/btnNao02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNao01"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNao01"
        android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSim02"
        android:text="nao" />

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/tvResposta02"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/btnSim02"
        android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
        android:text="texto com a resposta baseada na escolha do button " />

</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Coloque seu activity_main na sua pergunta.

Comment: vc fala do xml?

Comment: sim, exatamente.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nesta pergunta sobre [Layout não cabe na tela após rotação](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/questions/147684/layout-n%C3%A3o-cabe-na-tela-ap%C3%B3s-rota%C3%A7%C3%A3o/) possui uma resposta que pode resolver seu problema. Basicamente deve-se usar o `ScrollView` desta forma abaixo. Veja:

```
<ScrollView 
    ...
    ...
    <RelativeLayout
        ...
        ...

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Então seu arquivo `activity_main.xml` deve ficar assim:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent">

    <RelativeLayout
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPergunta01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:text="Pergunta 1" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResposta01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPergunta01"
            android:layout_marginTop="104dp"
            android:text="texto com a resposta baseada na escolha do button " />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvPergunta02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:text="pergunta 2" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSim01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPergunta01"
            android:layout_marginTop="26dp"
            android:text="sim" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNao01"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
            android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSim01"
            android:text="nao" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnSim02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignEnd="@+id/btnSim01"
            android:layout_alignRight="@+id/btnSim01"
            android:layout_below="@+id/tvPergunta02"
            android:layout_marginTop="68dp"
            android:text="sim" />

        <Button
            android:id="@+id/btnNao02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/btnNao01"
            android:layout_alignStart="@+id/btnNao01"
            android:layout_alignTop="@+id/btnSim02"
            android:text="nao" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/tvResposta02"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
            android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
            android:layout_below="@+id/btnSim02"
            android:layout_marginTop="46dp"
            android:text="texto com a resposta baseada na escolha do button " />

    </RelativeLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

Comment: agora como edito? a scroll view fica "empatando" tudo, não consigo por os components para fora dela

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso Se você está com dificuldade com scrollview para arrastar componentes na tela, aconselho primeiro você cria todo layout com todos os componentes e por ultimo você adiciona o scrollview.

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso Outro conselho que dou é, se seu _layout_ for muito grande, seria interessante, em vez de usar scrollview, criar uma lista dinâmica para adicionar essas questões. Pesquise um pouco sobre `RecyclerView`.

Comment: a solução temporária que encontrei foi colocar tanto o scrollview como o relativelayout com o height 2000dp, dessa forma consigo editar mais embaixo

Comment: Legal! Resolveu o problema? Precisa de mais algum exemplo?

Comment: ainda tenho que realizar mais testes. qq coisa aviso, já vou aceitar sua resp

Comment: @BonecoSinforoso Qualquer coisa estamos por aqui! Abs. Boa sorte!